# @:generic only for some type parameters

Tags: haxe

If I want to create class with 2 type parameters, and I want specialized implementation for every first type parameter used, but I do not want it for second type parameter.

For example I want my own Map

```
@:generic @:remove
class MyMap {
    public var map: Map<K, V> = new Map();
    public function new() {}
}
```

This will generate implementation for every combination of K and V used. But I want different implementations for K only.

I've tried making `abstract` over `@:generic` class with needed type parameter, or extending such class. But this does not work. Both ways haxe compiler generates creation of MyMapBase class, and does not generate that class at all.

```
@:generic @:remove
class MyMapBase<K> {
    public var map: Map<K, Dynamic> = new Map();
    public function new() {}
}

class MyMap1<K, V> extends MyMapBase<K> {
}

abstract MyMap2<K, V>(MyMapBase<K>) {
    public function new() {
        this = new MyMapBase();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I've used @:multiType abstract. This feature is not well documented in haxe, but one can look at Map implementation.

```
@:generic @:remove
class MyMapImpl<K> implements IMyMap<K, Dynamic> {
    public var map: Map<K, Dynamic> = new Map();
    public function new() {}
}

interface IMyMap<K, V> {
    public var map: Map<K, V>;
}

@:multiType(K)
abstract MyMap<K, V>(IMyMap<K, V>) {

    public function new();

    public var map(get, never): Map<K, V>;

    inline function get_map(): Map<K, V> {
        return this.map;
    }

    @:to static inline function toStringMap<K:String, V>(t:IMyMap<K, V>):MyMapImpl<String> {
        return cast new MyMapImpl<String>();
    }

    @:to static inline function toIntMap<K:Int, V>(t:IMyMap<K, V>):MyMapImpl<Int> {
        return cast new MyMapImpl<Int>();
    }
}


class Main {
    static function main() {
        var m = new MyMap<String, Int>();
        trace(Type.getClassName(Type.getClass(m))); //MyMapImpl_String
        trace(Type.getClassName(Type.getClass(m.map))); //haxe.ds.StringMap

        var m = new MyMap<String, String>();
        trace(Type.getClassName(Type.getClass(m))); //MyMapImpl_String
        trace(Type.getClassName(Type.getClass(m.map))); //haxe.ds.StringMap

        var m = new MyMap<Int, Int>(); 
        trace(Type.getClassName(Type.getClass(m))); //MyMapImpl_Int
        trace(Type.getClassName(Type.getClass(m.map))); //haxe.ds.IntMap
    }
}
```

Comment: That fails on static targets, for example error CS0400: The type or namespace name 'MyMapImpl' could not be found in the global namespace

Comment: I've fixed this. I've checked and it compiles and works now with hxcpp and haxe 4.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your own class at all. And since your values are stored as dynamic, you need only one instance of a map per key type. If that is not desired, you can change it back to instances per value, but then why to use dynamic values? Anyway, here is a map version which works across all targets.

```
@:multiType
abstract MyMap<K, V>(Map<K, Dynamic>) {

    public function new();

    public inline function set(k:K, v:V) this.set(k, v);
    public inline function get(k:K) return this.get(k);

    public static var string_map = new Map<String, Dynamic>();
    @:to static inline function toStringMap<K:String>(t:Map<K, Dynamic>) {
        return string_map;
    }

    public static var int_map = new Map<Int, Dynamic>();
    @:to static inline function toIntMap<K:Int>(t:Map<K, Dynamic>) {
        return int_map;
    }

    public static var object_map = new Map<{}, Dynamic>();
    @:to static inline function toObjectMap<K:{}>(t:Map<K, Dynamic>) {
        return object_map;
    }
}
```

```
    var i = new MyMap<String, Int>();
    i.set("zero", 0);
    trace(Type.getClassName(Type.getClass(i))); //haxe.ds.StringMap
    trace(i); // {zero => 0}
    var s = new MyMap<String, String>();
    s.set("one", "1");
    trace(Type.getClassName(Type.getClass(s))); //haxe.ds.StringMap
    trace(s); // {zero => 0, one => 1}
    // var v:Int = i.get("one") will fail on Java and HL
    // we let v to infer as Null<Dynamic> instead
    var v = i.get("one");
    trace(v);
```

Comment: MyMap is just an example. In my case I was creating an Map-like class, but with two different keys.

Comment: Why do you use static variables?

Comment: Because values are dynamic, everything can be stored in a single map per key type. That's why I use static variables. But you can go back to instance per value type, but then you shouldn't use dynamic as value type

Comment: In your example you create two different maps: `i` and `s`. You add `"zero"=>0` to `i` and `"one"=>1` to `s`. But later you trace `s` and it contains both values. It looks really strange.

Comment: It is not because you store dynamic values. What's the point of having different instances per value type, but then to store values as dynamic? It is a performance loss. And if you want to loose one performance (speed), at least you should improve another performance (memory consumption).

Comment: Your `trace(s)` was supposed to trace just `one=>1` , not `zero=>0, one=>1`. Because `zero` key was stored in `i`. You can optimize performance, but not at the cost of correct result. Also Map actually does not have different implementations for different value types, so if there are no safe casts (`cast(value, Type)` expressions), then there are no any performance loss.

Comment: Once again, it is like that because you are using dynamic values. You can change it back to return new instance per value type, but then you should avoid using dynamic. And if you think that conversion from dynamic to Int and back is not having performance impact, think again. Or at least, do some testing

Comment: When using non-generic type parameters in haxe, they are always stored as dynamic, because theres always one implementation for all different type parameters. But this actually does not lead to any performance loss, because it's there is no casting happens, or technically it's unsafe casts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204132/discussion-between-romamik-and-ilir-liburn).